# Как правильно сделать блок?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть блок `header` и `slider`, как сделать, чтобы `slider` был определенной высоты (например, 80% экрана), а внизу оставалась еще `section`?
Установить высоту не получается в %, только в px.

```css
#header {
    padding: 1%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #7fb311;
    color: #fff;
    height: auto;
}

#slider {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/2946/dawn-nature-sunset-trees.jpg") center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#slider .section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #7fb311;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  HEADER
</div>

<div id="slider">
  <div class="section">
    AAA BBB CCC
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aqsrgd1t/

Comment: А `section` должен занимать всё остальное пространство?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, Нет, лишь 70% внизу slider

Comment: Сейчас дополню. Так что `section` снизу уже не надо?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov нужен, пытаюсь его разместить внизу `slider` по центру, добавил `postion: absolute; margin: auto`, но `section` остается внизу, но слева

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для установки размеров относительно экрана используйте единицы измерения `vh` что означает viewport height.

```
#slider {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

---

Полный пример (стили по умолчанию или нерелеватные опущены).

```css
#header {
  background-color: #7fb311;
  color: #fff;
}

#slider {
  height: 80vh;
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/2946/dawn-nature-sunset-trees.jpg") center;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

#slider .section {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #7fb311;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  HEADER
</div>

<div id="slider">
  <div class="section">
    AAA BBB CCC
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: только не width, а height. для width - 80vw

Comment: Спасибо за внимательность, видимо, вредно пытаться одновременно работать и отвечать на SO.

Comment: Ну и с поддержкой в IE могут быть проблемы. Если верить http://caniuse.com/#search=vh только 11-я версия частично поддерживает эти единицы измерения

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, спасибо!

Comment: @humster_spb поддержка IE9+ существует, просто посмотрите на другие вкладки там же, к примеру "Usage relative".

Comment: Всё равно дополнил, чтобы `section` было снизу. Этот пример будет работать на IE11, но можно сделать чтобы работал на IE10.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, всё работает, спасибо)